# Inserting comments column next to Power Query Table

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I want to add a column where I write notes for that row of data in the table that has been generated by PowerQuery. The notes stay for that row only, but when I refresh the query and new data comes through, the notes in that row stay in that row. I want it to move with its corresponding data. How can I do this? Can someone please give me step by step instructions?

```
row 1: 1 - hello

row 2: 2 - bye

row 3: 3 - ok

...
```

Refresh power query results:

```
row 1: 0 - hello

row 2: 1 - bye

row 3: 2 - ok

...
```

Wanted results:

```
row 1: 0 -

row 2: 1 - hello

row 3: 2 - bye

row 4: 3 - ok

...
```

where the number are the column in power query, and the text is comments i have made in the same row, next to the table.

Answer (score 1):

see instructions for self-referential tables at https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/